# hive comment get NULL in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I execute `"ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN col_name col_name column_type COMMENT col_comment;"` to add comment to my table, and I succeeded.In hive I desc my table and I got like this:

```
hive> desc mytable;

+---------+----------+---------+
|col_name |data_type |comment  |
|---------+----------+---------+
|col1     |string    |name     |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

but in spark-sql the comment is gone:

```
spark-sql> desc mytable;

+---------+----------+---------+
|col_name |data_type |comment  |
|---------+----------+---------+
|col1     |string    |null     |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

By the way, I use MySQL for metastore.
How can I get the comment in spark-sql?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Spark interacts with the Metastore as little as possible, and supports only a few core Hive features. Or, maybe, if you have the WebHCat service running, you could send a custom HTTP query then parse the JSON response to retrieve the full table structure.

Comment: You can directly connect to MySQL using jdbc and retrieve meta information.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The truth is I got my comment in spark-sql in the test  environment，but i failed in the production environment. But I don't konw why.